# Rendering a 2.79b file in Blender 2.80

Tags: rendering

I have created a shockwave in Blender 2.79b. I used 2.79 as it was easier for me to follow the tutorial. Now when I open that blend file in 2.80, the render results are not the same as 2.79b. I tried with both eevee and cycles. It seems 2.80 isn't recognizing the material and the compositing I did in 2.79b. Is there a way around this? Thanks

[image]
[image]

Danny

Comment: Are you using Blender Internal for 2.79b? 2.80 doesn't have BI for rendering. Or is there a node setup screen shot so we can take a look at what might be the problem.

Comment: I think it could be caused by the fact that in 2.79, I added a new material and changed it to halo. I can't find this "halo" in the material in 2.80, the only place I find it is in particles. I just loaded the blend file in 2.80 and there is no particle system enabled. Could that be the issue? I will get node setup screen shots and post them.

Comment: Definitely yes, some obsolete feature will no longer support in new Cycles build. They will possibly contain in **custom properties**, you can check that block to see what is thrown there.

Comment: 10-4. Figured it could be that. I just added my nodes to my original question. So I guess I have to figure out how to do that shockwave tutorial in 2.80 instead of 2.79.... seems I will be learning Blender for years to come lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a **Blender Internal** render engine setting. It is not for **Cycles**, they don't use same material system(although they are all using node).

You **will not able to directly import** this material into Blender 2.80 and further version. Since they've discarded the old **BI** system and adopt EEVEE, which share the same material system, instead.

You might find out that node setting in 2.81(newest one) could probably do the same effect with more elegant node setting. Keep on keeping on.

Comment: There are some add-on which can help you to turn BI material into Cycles one. Then you can import it to 2.80. But AFAIK, add-on only work on simple material. And the setting should  be messy and need further cleanup. Which is kind of...useless, in my mind

Comment: I just downloaded 2.81. Will read up on the changes and attempt that tutorial with it. At the very least, I will LEARN, which is my number 1 goal.... completing my project is a close second!